# How to find the class to which text belong?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am working on simple web scraper where I am trying to look for product dimensions at google preview page. I am using libraries  "beautiful" soup and re" in tempt to retrieve the information. 
If I lookup one item and go to source page i can identify the class to which description belongs and i can simply use:

```
soup.find(class_="st") and get results like this:
```

Part Number, **DCD771B**. Item Weight, 2.8 pounds. Package **Dimensions**, 10.8 x 
8.2 x 3.5 inches. Item model number, **DCD771B**. Power Source, battery-powered.

While this works beautifully if the dimensions are always in same class, i am unable to find the way to retrieve this info if the Dimensions not always in that class. So my idea was to try to retrive the class to which word Dimensions belong, and then use same code above. 
I have tried this code: 
   soup.find_all(text = "Dimensions")
which returns the list with 3 elements meaning it find 3 classes that contain word "Dimensions. 
How can i retrieve the class name to which word  dimensions belongs?
here is portion of Html from which im trying to retrive Class name by using word "Dimensions"

```
 html = """<span class="st">
          Part Number,
          <b>
           DCD771B
          </b>
          . Item Weight, 2.8 pounds. Package
          <b>
           Dimensions
          </b>
          , 10.8 x
          <br/>
          8.2 x 3.5 inches. Item model number,
          <b>
           DCD771B
          </b>
          . Power Source, battery-powered.
         </span> """
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably have a little more work to do with this to work somethings out. This might not cover all the bases, so to speak. BUT this should get you going.

Essentially, you'll just be grabbing the parent tags, and then use `.attrs` when you iterate over your 3 elements that you find with "Dimensions". You can see how it works by playing around with the code below.

```
import bs4
import re

html = """<span class="st">
          Part Number,
          <b>
           DCD771B
          </b>
          . Item Weight, 2.8 pounds. Package
          <b>
           Dimensions
          </b>
          , 10.8 x
          <br/>
          8.2 x 3.5 inches. Item model number,
          <b>
           DCD771B
          </b>
          . Power Source, battery-powered.
         </span> """


soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')




tag_name = soup.find(text=re.compile('Dimensions')).parent.parent.name
attributes = soup.find(text=re.compile('Dimensions')).parent.parent.attrs

class_name = soup.find(text=re.compile('Dimensions')).parent.parent.attrs['class'][0]
```

**Output:**

```
print (tag_name)
span

print(attributes)
{'class': ['st']}

print(class_name)
st
```

Comment: thank you, this did the trick and worked perfectly for what i needed. :-)